Reproject NetCDF from Azimuthal to Mercator projection in QGIS
How can I convert Azimuthal projection to classical Mercator projection?
I need it for a scientific project on soil temperatures and permafrost, but no matter how hard I try to reproject the map, I can’t, the format is strange.
Link to the map - https://catalogue.ceda.ac.uk/uuid/67a3f8c8dc914ef99f7f08eb0d997e23
how does it turn out

how I want it to turn out in the end


What did you try?

What do you mean by classical Mercator projection do you mean https://epsg.org/crs_3857/WGS-84-Pseudo-Mercator.html ?

yes, when reprojected into qgis, the raster is not rotated but remains in the same projection

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Instead of stating you tried a bunch of things, please choose one thing you tried and detail the exact procedure you used, and the exact problem encountered.

nc format rasters are not reprojected in the usual way, I don’t choose which projection, it still turns out arctic, but I need it to be like in the second picture, how can I do this? Try downloading the file I talked about from the nc website and working with it.

Did you try to add the reprojected data to an empty qgis project?
